# Were children ever given the honor of reading the Torah scroll in the first century?

Tags: history, halacha-theory, sefer-torah

Given that in the first century, Jewish boys were taught the Torah from ~6 to 10 in the synagogue, was there ever any likelihood of an exceptionally-literate and gifted pupil being selected to read from the Torah Scroll on the sabbath day?

As far as I'm aware, only adults got up to read the scroll. But is there a historical record of any child (even from an apocryphal or legendary source) being given the honor to read?

Comment: Why is this tagged `christianity`?

Comment: @ezra because the question is asking about a story in luke where jesus got haftara, probably trying to prove that jesus was an adult

Comment: @DoubleAA But if that were true, the question still shouldn't be so, as Jesus apparently received the Haftarah when he was an adult man. So why is this tagged `christianity`? The question still remains.

Comment: @ezra oh probably because the op does know tagging rules and conventions around here

Comment: If it is a question about the mythology of that other religion it would be closed as not being about Judaism.

Comment: What's a Moses seat?

Comment: @heshy it's a thing mentioned in Christian Bible . See http://mi.yodeya.com/a/25883

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm not in charge of interpreting their scriptures, but it seems to me that he's talking about Moses' position, not his literal seat. So no solid proof there what a Moses seat is.

Comment: "...Adults sat on the Moses-seat and got up to read the scroll, after which they would give a short little homily." How do you know this? Doesn't sound like normal synagogue procedure to me. And what is a Moses-seat? We stand while reading from the Torah.

Comment: I believe the custom in Yemen was for children to read from the Torah if they were skilled enough to do so.

Comment: Can someone describe to me why the edits don't make the question available for re-opening?

Answer (score 5):

According to the mishna in [Megila 4:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Megillah.4.6), a child is allowed to read from the Torah, and so it's safe to assume that it was done sometimes.

> **קָטָן קוֹרֵא בַּתּוֹרָה וּמְתַרְגֵּם**, אֲבָל אֵינוֹ פּוֹרֵס עַל שְׁמַע,
> וְאֵינוֹ עוֹבֵר לִפְנֵי הַתֵּיבָה, וְאֵינוֹ נוֹשֵׂא אֶת כַּפָּיו.

> **A minor may read in the Torah [in the synagogue], and act as
> meturgeman,** but may not publicly recite the Shema, nor act as minister
> at the tebah, nor [if a priest] say [by himself] the blessing of
> priests.

---

###on a side note:

The Bartenura [says](https://www.sefaria.org/Bartenura_on_Mishnah_Megillah.4.6.1) that there are some Geonim who say that a child may only read from the third Aliya and on:

> **קטן קורא בתורה:**. ויש מן הגאונים שאמרו דוקא משלישי ואילך

But not everyone holds like the Mishna Le'halacha

Yachin on Mishnah Megillah [says:](https://www.sefaria.org/Yachin_on_Mishnah_Megillah.4.41.1)

> **קטן קורא בתורה ומתרגם:** וקיי"ל דאין הקטן רשאי להיות קורא בצבור עד שיביא ב' שערות. אבל שיהיה בכלל הקרואים, י"א דוקא אחר שלישי רשאי ואנן
> נוהגין דרק להיות מפטיר מותר [מג"א רפ"ב סק"ו]:
>
> And we established that a child may not read from the Torah, until he
> has grown two [pubic] hairs. But to be part of the ones called to the Torah, there are
> those who say that he may do so. But we hold, that
> he may only be called for Maftir.
> (Translation is my own)

According to the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch, ([23:24](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Arukh.23.24)) a child may not read from the Torah in public:

> קטן לא יהיה הקורא, וגם אינו עולה לתורה.

> A minor (less than thirteen
> years old) cannot be the reader and is not called to be an oleh.

Comment: And if it's Maftir/Haftorah, that's even clearer in the Mishnah.

Comment: @Shalom I'm not sure I'm following. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: Any reason as to why eventually a child was excluded except for maftir? (BTW, I have NEVER seen this done) Does it have anything to do with *kavod hatzibur*?

Comment: @DanF I've seen it once. I haven't found a reason as to why some say only Maftir can be done, but I remember hearing that it has to do with the fact that maftir is extra to the kriya.

Comment: @DanF a rebbe of mine said that when he was a child it was done weekly in his shul (ultra orthodox)

Comment: @ABochur Yes, maftir is "extra". That reasoning makes me think that there is a *kavod hatzibur* aspect in this decision. A hunch, here.